# What should I backup?

Tags: backup

I have backups from a couple of old desktop/laptop installation - most of which do not exist anymore. Which of the following folders or files can I savely remove because I will never need them anymore:

`bin`, `boot`, `.config`, `.config.log`, `copy-logs`, `cdrom`, `dev`, `initrd`, `initrd.img`, `initrd.img.old`, `.kde`, `.kde.log`, `lib`, `lib64`, `root`, `sbin`, `srv`, `usr`

*To clarify:* These are not on my current operating system. They once where in `/` of the previous systems, but are now somewhere on an external hard drive.

*I have more folders in the root directories of those backups*, but for those others I am rather sure I know whether I can delete them or might still need them (e.g. I know I have to keep `home` or I know I can safely remove `run`.) I am not so sure about these here. For most I know what they contain, but still aren't sure whether that means I can delete them. Can you help?

Please explain for the respective folder why I won't need it, so that I may sleep well at night ;-).

Comment: Looks like "none of the above" (those are from a full backup of your machine).

Comment: @ThomasDickey: Yes, I did full backups - because at the time I did not know what made sense so I just copied everything. Now I'd like to get rid of the stuff I'll never need. Please explain why I won't need it - if possible - so I may sleep well at night :-). Thank you very much.

Comment: The question is: what would you missing the next day, if someone stole your desktop during the night? Isn't it about time to switch to a tablet (use it at home with big screen, keyboard and mouse), that does continuesly updates?

Comment: @ott-- First of all: Sure, continuous backups are good practise, but that is a different question. Here I am talking about systems I had saved before destroying them (e.g. to make way for another installation or because I switched hardware). Secondly, what do you mean with "tablet"? How is a tablet helping you opposed to a desktop or a laptop?

Comment: Why do you need system files for old systems that do not exist anymore? Answer that and you'll know what you should keep. Also, what do you mean by safe, since they aren't part of anything, why would it be unsafe not to have them?

Comment: @Christia: Well, my thought was, that one day I might want to use a program again. Then I could copy required files over. (Maybe settings or something like that.) I am not sure if that even makes sense - whether there are any files that I might want in a situation like that. In a way, that is what I am asking: Whether there are directories that make (any) sense keeping.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the pathnames listed look like parts of your *system* (which you would not want to remove from the disk, and are not really necessary on a *backup*, since any serious damage to those would require a reinstall):

```
/bin, /boot, /.config, /.config.log, /copy-logs, /cdrom, /dev,
/initrd, /initrd.img, /initrd.img.old, /.kde, /.kde.log, /lib,
/lib64, /root, /sbin, /srv, /usr
```

Normally your own files would be under `/home` (actually, I use `/users` on my machines — `useradd` is flexible).  I would have expected a backup to be for your home directory, but do not see that in the list.

To restore a whole system from backups, you should of course be able to run the backup program in single-user mode.  That's kind of awkward unless the program is designed for that purpose.  If you don't have a suitable program for restoring, then a full backup is of limited usefulness.

If those folders are backups from *another* system, they can be discarded, since none are (a) backups of your home-directory or (b) backups of the existing system:

- bin, boot, dev, initrc, lib, lib64, root, sbin and usr are all standard filesystem items.  Except for root, these would contain things *installed* (from CDROMs or other media), while `/root` is the **root** user's home directory.  If you did not stage builds from that directory, it is probably empty (other than, say, an install log). `/dev`, by the way, is usually generated (though occasionally someone by mistake puts a file there).
- .config and .config.log looks like leftovers from building a kernel
- .kde, .kde.log likewise build/install for KDE
- initrc, initrd.img likewise from building/installing a kernel
- cdrom normally is just a mountpoint (and empty)
- copy-logs and srv are something to verify, but from being in the "/" level are likely artifacts of the backup, or like the others

Further reading:

- [1.19. /srv](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/srv.html) (Linux Filesystem Hierarchy)
- [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/index.html)

Comment: I clarified by question a bit: These are not on my system - they are on an external hard drive somewhere from old systems. As I had mentioned they are also only those folders I am not sure about - e.g. I am sure about `home` (must keep) or `run` (can delete).

Comment: Well, keeping `home` is not enough. E.g. I also should keep `etc` and `opt` and some subfolders in `var`. (Those were not mentioned above, because I already know that, but it shows that keeping home and discarding everything else is a bit hasty.)

Comment: `etc` can be helpful in seeing how to transplant settings, but `opt` usually is stuff to reinstall

Comment: I am mostly interested in those folders in your first bullet point: `bin`, `boot`, `lib`, `lib64`, `root`, `sbin`, `usr`. I have a (very rough) idea what they contain, but am not quite sure why I should never need their contents anymore. Can you elaborate for each of those?

Comment: Don't forget `/usr/local`.   `/usr` itself probably isn't worth restoring (as it mostly contains files available in distro packages), **except** for `/usr/local` if it exists and is non-empty.

Comment: The thought crossed my mind, but OP seems to not be a developer (who would have used /usr/local).

Comment: @ThomasDickey: As a matter of fact... I **am** a developer. (Or rather, I am programming, since it is not my focus and do other types of programming than you'd probably expect. Instead it "just comes with the job"). These have been my private machines with which I have not been developing, but please: If in doubt, tell me I might have to backup ;-).

Comment: well... if you have anything substantial in `/usr/local`, that might be useful - if the operating system is compatible (same system or later version of the same).  I used to copy `/usr/local` in setting up a new machine, but for several years have built packages for everything.